# How to add a space to the end of a string?

Tags: php, string

I searched online and found the [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function but this is not what I need. I need to automatically add a space at the end of a string.

The string value returned can be my default value or a custom value supplied by an extending developer. If the developer supplies extra characters, which they can, then the `str_pad()` approach won't always work.

Is there a simple function for this to ALWAYS add one space to the end of a string? Like a `trim()` but works the opposite?

Here is what I am doing.

```
str_pad($this->filter('custom_hook_name', FALSE, 'column span-12'), 15);
```

My default is `'column span-12'`

However the developer might return their custom classes as well so the return string value could look something like...

```
'dev-brand-column span-12'

'dev-brand-col col-12'

// etc...
```

I need to add a space as the end of the string regardless of the string length.

How can I achieve that? I find nothing that works the opposite of [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) like.

Comment: What if there already is a space at the end of the string, do you still want to add one?

Comment: `$string = $string. ' ';` is the easiest way to do this, the `.` is responsible for concatenation in php

Comment: `str_pad($this->filter('custom_hook_name', FALSE, 'column span-12'), strlen($this->filter('custom_hook_name', FALSE, 'column span-12'))+1);` :)

Comment: @NineBerry my purpose is that I don't want developers to be concerned with returning a space at the end of the string because if they forget then it will join css classes together ruining the output so I want to handle it on my side to ensure the output passed it correct. The rtrim() will be ideal to avoid an issue like that.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - Thanks! Yeah, too much thinking that I missed that method. :( REALLY THANKS!!! I will try to think less next time, lol.

Comment: Another way: If you have a list of class names, you can apply `trim` on all class names in the list and then use `join` to combine them together into one string adding a space in between all of them.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks! A little less ideal though as I would have to add this to several filters I have running. But I think your method works as well :D (I didn't test)

Comment: @NineBerry thanks! Yep. Good idea. If I use an array I will update! Appreciate it! Thanks about the join() function, simple to remember than implode for me.

Comment: @NoahjChampion don&#39;t worry I overtime something simple day to day ;) happy to help though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)  to first remove all whitespace at the end of the string that might be there, then add one space yourself:

```
$str = rtrim($str) . " ";
```

Comment: just as a reference point in case anyone wants to look at `rtrim` http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: Thanks! Ahh... I don't know why I was just over thinking adding a space like this. Appreciate it! Thanks for the fallback on the rtrim as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think that sprintf() can help you...

For example :

```
$string = "Bond";
printf("%-10s",    $string);
```

Will return :

```
Bond
```

With 6 spaces at the end of the string.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `sprintf` seems a bit ott when you can just concat

Comment: This basically has the same issue as using str_pad. You need to specify a desired length. Multiple spaces are added when the string is short. No space is added when the string is too long.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I saw this answer out there when I found the str_pad() method. It's not what I was looking for either, but I forgot to mention it when I posted as I had already ruled it out.